# Reveal hover effect as click on iphone

Tags: html, ios, iphone, hover, background-image

I have an interesting issue, which I really hope someone can help med with.
I have created a fiddle, which shows the code I have on the website I am working on.

The problem:
I have a hover effect, which reveals a background image. On android a simple click also reveals the image, however this does not work on iPhones. Does anyone know how to fix that? I just want the image to be revealed by one click - there are no links or anything :)

The fiddle is here: https://jsfiddle.net/tLojh36u/

```
<div class="row no-gutters">
    <div class="col-md-8 mx-auto">
      <h2 class="pt-5 text-uppercase">Krom & Nikkellegeringer</h2>
      <div class="metal-container d-flex flex-wrap">
        <div id="krom1" class="metal-item text-center flex-column shadow-sm">
          <h3>Rustfri stål 304</h3>
        </div>
        <div id="krom2" class="metal-item text-center flex-column shadow-sm">
          <h3>Rustfri stål 316</h3>
        </div>
        <div id="krom3" class="metal-item text-center flex-column shadow-sm">
          <h3>Rustfri spåner</h3>
        </div>
        <div id="krom5" class="metal-item text-center flex-column shadow-sm">
          <h3>Kromstål</h3>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

The CSS can be seen in the fiddle

Comment: I solved it myself by adding onClick"return true" to the metal-items :)

Answer (score 0):

I solved it myself by adding onClick"return true" to the metal-items :)